# Trapping warnings without translating them to errors

Tags: r

I have a need to trap warnings (in R) without interfering with the operation of the mixed
model that is generating them. I have looked at two variations of this so far. In
one case, where an error occurs that causes the model to fall over, I am happily
able to record fitted objects from those instances when the model run is sucessful with a record of the failures interspersed:

```
storOutcomes<-lapply(1:50, function(i)tryCatch(CustomlmerFnctn(Datasets[[i]]),
error=function(e) NULL ))
```

In the second case I can change warnings into errors using options(warn=2) and use a
similar syntax to that above. However, I can’t see how to record both the fitted
objects and the status of the convergence i.e., at least two warnings appear, either

```
“In mer_finalize (ans) : singular convergence (7)”
```

or

```
“In mer_finalize (ans) : false convergence (8)“
```

and I want to be able to link the status of the convergence to the model parameters.
So essentially I want to know how to trap the warnings without translating them into
errors. I have tried a combination of `options(warn=1)`, `suppressMessages`, and `sink(…,
type(“output”,”message”))` with a `cat()` statement producing an iteration/dataset ID
from the model function, but this only writes the consecutive ID to file, leaving
the warning on the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your complicated example, but maybe

```
warn <- NULL
value <- withCallingHandlers({
    warning("oops")
    1 + 2
}, warning = function(w) {
    warn <<- append(warn, conditionMessage(w))
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

Leading to

```
> warn
[1] "oops"
> value
[1] 3
```

This is also illustrated on `?withCallingHandlers` and its additional documentation `demo(error.catching)`. `muffleWarning` is mentioned on `?warning`.

Comment: Many thanks Martin - I'm uncertain about the difference between a created warning and a standard warning that is generated from the model run - see examples in my original post. How would your code change if it was storing such a warning?

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand; `CustomlmerFnctn` is likely generating a warning by saying `warning("singular convergence (7)")` or similar, and the warning would be handled as in my answer. Maybe if you provided an easily reproducible example it would be clearer?

Comment: I guess I mean that you would only need to remove the "oops" from the warning call as follows                                     warn <- NULL
value <- withCallingHandlers({
    warning()
    CustomlmerFnctn()
}, warning = function(w) {
    warn <<- append(warn, conditionMessage(w))
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})

Comment: Thanks again Martin - when I tried your suggestion with my real example it wasn't generating the warning as I expected so thought the code needed some tweak - I have it working now.